# Get Latest Message for a Confluent Kafka Topic in Python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform, confluent-kafka-python

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
from confluent_kafka import Consumer

c = Consumer({... several security/server settings skipped...
              'auto.offset.reset': 'beginning',
              'group.id': 'my-group'})

c.subscribe(['my.topic'])
msg = poll(30.0)  # msg is of None type.
```

`msg` almost always ends up being `None` though. I think the issue might be that `'my-group'` has already consumed all the messages for `'my.topic'`... but I don't care whether a message has already been consumed or not - I still need the latest message. Specifically, I need the timestamp from that latest message.

I tried a bit more, and from this it looks like there are probably 25 messages in the topic, but I have no idea how to get at them:

```
a = c.assignment()
print(a)  # Outputs [TopicPartition{topic=my.topic,partition=0,offset=-1001,error=None}]
offsets = c.get_watermark_offsets(a[0])
print(offsets)  # Outputs: (25, 25)
```

If there are no messages because the topic has never had anything written to it at all, how can I determine that? And if that's the case, how can I determine how long the topic has existed for? I'm looking to write a script that automatically deletes any topics that haven't been written to in the past X days (14 initially - will probably tweak it over time.)

Answer (score 9):

I run into the same issue, and no example on this. In my case there is one partition, and I need to read the last message, to know the some info from that message to setup the consumer/producer component I have.

Logic is that start `Consumer`, subscribe to topic, poll for message -> this triggers `on_assign`, where the rewinding happens, by assigning the modified partitions back. After `on_assign` finishes, the poll for `msg` continues and reads the last message from topic.

```
settings = {
    "bootstrap.servers": "my.kafka.server",
    "group.id": "my-work-group",
    "client.id": "my-work-client-1",
    "enable.auto.commit": False,
    "session.timeout.ms": 6000,
    "default.topic.config": {"auto.offset.reset": "largest"},
}
consumer = Consumer(settings)

def on_assign(a_consumer, partitions):
    # get offset tuple from the first partition
    last_offset = a_consumer.get_watermark_offsets(partitions[0])
    # position [1] being the last index
    partitions[0].offset = last_offset[1] - 1
    consumer.assign(partitions)

consumer.subscribe(["test-topic"], on_assign=on_assign)

msg = consumer.poll(6.0)
```

Now `msg` is having the last message inside.

Comment: This actually helped me. In case you have multiple partitions, you loop of the partitions and update the offset. After that, your consumer will get the newest messages.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone still needs an example for case with multiple partitions; this is how I did it:

```
from confluent_kafka import OFFSET_END, Consumer

settings = {
    'bootstrap.servers': "my.kafka.server",
    'group.id': "my-work-group",
    'auto.offset.reset': "latest"
}

def on_assign(consumer, partitions):
    for partition in partitions:
        partition.offset = OFFSET_END
    consumer.assign(partitions)


consumer = Consumer(settings)

consumer.subscribe(["test-topic"], on_assign=on_assign)

msg = consumer.poll(1.0)
```